# Access dynamic value to delete object key

Tags: jquery, html

I am adding items to an object and I need to be able to delete them.

```
<div class="list">
    <span class="itemName">Item Name</span>
    <a href="#" class="expand"></a>

    <ul class="options">
          <h5> Options </h5>
          <li><a href="#" class="add">Add Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="delete">Delete Item</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

```js
var tableData = {};

$(".delete").click(function() {
    var tmp = $(this).parent().parent().parent().next().val();
    delete tableData[tmp];
)};
```

I need to get the "Item Name" because it is the key for the object I need to delete. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: What is `this` a reference to? I also assume that `tableData` holds some properties that you omitted in the question?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited the original post, sorry forgot to include! `tableData` simply holds a list of "Item Name" objects that have lots of nesting that's irrelevant to the question I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you can use `closest()` instead of multiple chained `parent()` calls. Secondly, `next()` looks for siblings, yet you need to find `.itemName` which is a child so you need to use `find()`. Finally, only form inputs have a value which can be retrieved via `val()`. In this case you would need `text()` or `html()`. Try this:

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    var tmp = $(this).closest('.list').find('.itemName').text();
    delete tableData[tmp];
});
```

Also note that your closing bracket/brace was the wrong way around. It should be `})`, not `)}`.

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/d34bty7y/)

Comment: In the `console.log` shouldn't the `bar` be gone after being deleted from `tableData` ?

Comment: But it works! I was unsure about using `.val()` but thank you for the clarification.

Comment: No, only `foo` as that's the value in `itemName`